# Passing a value from Perl to an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, perl

There is a button present in HTML, which when pressed the `OnClick` function should run a Perl file and get a variable's value from Perl file and display it on HTML file.

Unfortunately AJAX call can't be used in Perl. I tried so many ways, but none of the ideas passed. Could anyone please say what other methods can be used to solved this problem?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why can't you use asynchronous calls? What does *"none of the ideas passed"* mean? Have you written some Perl code that you need help with? If not, then why not?

Comment: Why do you think AJAX can't be used in Perl? I use it all the time.

Comment: @cajwine: i guess i told that I can't use AJAX call, if you have some answer please help. I think now you can understand

Comment: @SantoshSahu ... what? I have no idea what "I guess I told" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @melpomene: "I guess I told" is I already mentioned in the question that I can't use AJAX to solve the problem.

Comment: I clearly asked, if there is any other way we can solve problem without using AJAX calls, if people don't have answer please don't demoralize the question by giving negative points and unuseful answers.

Comment: You said in your question, *“Unfortunately AJAX call can't be used in Perl”* which isn't true; AJAX *can* be used in Perl. If you meant that you don't *want* or are not *allowed* to do so then you should say so. If you spend a little more time explaining your circumstances and your problem you will get much better answers; as it it you have just confused us

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an ajax call, then your onclick call will need to basically do a redirect to your perl script and the perl script will need to output a full page rather than just updating a portion of the current page. Something like this:

```
onclick="self.location='perlscript.pl?param1=value1&param2=value2'"
```

Comment: thanks very much, already had this idea in my mind.